# ¿Cómo dividir en secciones una iutableview en swift 2?

Tags: swift2

Tengo una `tableview` con 270 celdas que van abrir 30 PDFs.

Algunas de ellas repiten el mismo PDF.

Todo funciona perfectamente pero no no consigo crear secciones para que se vea dividido por orden alfabético. Sólo necesito que se vea la sección `A` y sus elementos, sección `B` y sus elementos.

Comment: tienes que dividirla en secciones.

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza los métodos delegados para especificar la cantidad de secciones y las celdas por sección:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 2

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    switch section {
    case 0:
        return 20

    case 1:
        return 10

    default:
        return 0

    }

}
```

Después, solo tienes que utilizar `indexPath.row` y `indexPath.section` para distinguir en que sección y celda estás.

Answer (score 1):

La primera cosa que te debes plantear es si quieres sacar una sección por cada letra del abecedario, tenga o no tenga un PDF que mostrar, o si por el contrario solo quieres la sección si tiene algo que mostrar, por ejemplo con la A si tienes algún PDF con A, si no tienes ninguna con B, pues no tendrías sección B. Esto depende de como lo quieras. Si quieres mostrar todas las secciones, podrías crearte un array con todas las letras del abecedario (por si quieres poner la Ñ por ejemplo) y luego lo vas a usar como base pasa sacar las secciones y el titulo de la sección. No nos indicas si los datos están en CoreData, en un Array o como tienes implementado el modelo.

Créate un array al principio con las secciones que quieres tener.

```
let secciones = ["A","B","C","D"]   //termina de rellenarlo
```

Rellenas el array con las letras que quieres que aparezcan en las secciones.
Ahora tienes que implementar los métodos delegados

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

return secciones.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

// aquí debes poder sacar de tu modelo los PDF que correspondan a cada letra.
//La letra la obtienes de esta forma: let letra = secciones[section]
//y sabiendo la letras tienes que poder sacar de alguna forma cuantos PDF hay con esa letra
}
```

Para sacar el titulo de cada sección:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
return secciones[section]
}
```

Si lo que quieres es la otra opción, es muy similar a esta, solo que el array secciones con todas las letras estaría relleno con las letras que quieres que aparezcan. Deberias inicializar el array en el método viewDidLoad() por ejemplo, con los valores que tienes en tu modelo y todo lo demás seria similar